# facebook page plugin not displaying on my website

Tags: facebook

I followed these instructions ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin ), but all I get is a     link to the Facebook page. The page is not being embedded into my website.

My code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>facebook</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>



<div class="fb-page" data-    href="https://www.facebook.com/christpalaceinternational" data-width="320" data-   height="500" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-   posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote    cite="https://www.facebook.com/christpalaceinternational"><a   href="https://www.facebook.com/christpalaceinternational">CHRIST PALACE   MINISTRIES INTERNATIONAL</a></blockquote></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `data-    href` – do you actually have those spaces in there? That has to be `data-href` of course. (And for the other `data-` attributes as well.)

Comment: Artem: can you confirm if the suggestion by CBroe fix you issue?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134145/1956964

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I checked the documentation and it says to take off all restrictions by age, country, ect. As the facebook restrictions will be embedded on to your site. Therefore:

- Plugin will render normally as expected for those who are not restricted.
- Plugin would not render at all for those who are restricted.