# Facebook Page Plugin appears as link only on website

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, facebook-social-plugins

I have seen similar posts, but haven't found an answer. I am rebuilding my website using Bootstrap and would like to add the new Page Plugin. I have followed all the instructions, inserting the Javascript code after the opening  tag and inserting the other code into my web page. All that appears on my webpage is a link that reads "KMC Marine", which DOES go to my Facebook page, but no other plugin data appears.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

1) put following css code, it will solve your problem

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fb_iframe_widget span{        
        overflow: initial !important;
    }
    .fb_iframe_widget iframe{        
        width: 340px !important;
        height: 500px !important;    
    }
</style>
```

2) if you are running your website locally you have to replace

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

with

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

Comment: How do you set the CSS so it fits into the code without laying out over everything... for some reason my footer appears to the side of it as oppose to under it?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the JS code before the ending body tag as opposed to after the opening tag.

Comment: Hi Lansana, Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same result. Very strange. I see that other people are having the same issue.

Comment: Do you have the <div id="fb-root"></div> code in your file as well? So there's three things required: 1. the JavaScript, 2. the <div> with all of the Facebook attributes, 3. the div I mentioned at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: Hi Lansana, Yes, I did include the "fb-root" div information in my code. I've tried including it before the script, as Facebook suggests. I've also tried including it before (or surrounding) the code where the plugin should appear on my webpage. Each time, I get the same result.

Comment: Try putting the fb-root with the script at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag. Also make sure you have properly linked the code.. with your Facebook url.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I did like you did, included the sdk Javascript right after the body tag (and before, or on a separate javascript file, anywhere else, doesn't matter, still doesn't work!!!) and I placed the code of my plugin where I want it to appear.

I had this error in the browser console :

GET file://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(anonymous function)

So I tried to change this :

```
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

into this :

```
   js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
```

The SDK now seems to load but I have a new error in the console :

Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. (sdk.js, line 64).

You can still try this. Maybe it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my problem was that I hadn't uploaded the site to the web. I was simply testing the site in a browser before uploading. Once I uploaded it, the plugin worked fine.

See if that works for you!

:) Nancy