# Facebook Page Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

there's a problem at installing the new facebook page plugin. I create a simple test.html file with the following code including the plugin-code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin. But there is an error message from my browser that file://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4 cannot find on the server. I also completed the adress by http: or saved the Facebook-file local and embedded it as a local js-file, but the page plugin doesn't appear. What's the problem?!

HTML-Code in test.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134145/1956964

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be including an App ID in your URL for the SDK request. If you have not yet created an App ID, you can do so here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Note the appended `&appId=[APP_ID_NUMBER_GOES_HERE]` in the example below from my Website (real App ID removed, obviously)

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=[APP_ID_NUMBER_GOES_HERE]";
```

The Facebook SDK quick start guide and documentation should answer any other question you have about getting started: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.4

Comment: But in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs facebook says that "you do not need to create a Facebook app for integrating a Social Plugin" or "to have a Facebook Developer account". In fact there are websites (http://lars-castellucci.de for example), which exactly using the code from facebook, which I put in the example above. The only thing I did is copying the code from facebook and putting it into the simplest html-file you can create - and it doesn't work. Seems a little bit strange to me...

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed the problem. The only thing I had to do is uploading my site to an online server.